# Extracting normals of a CGALTriangulation

Tags: c++, geometry, cgal, triangulation

In a 3D CGALTriangulation I'm trying to get the normals by this way

```
    Vector n = CGAL::normal(p1, p2, p3);
```

Code in context:

```
for (CGALTriangulation::Finite_facets_iterator it = T.finite_facets_begin();
             it != T.finite_facets_end();
             it++)
        {
            std::pair<CGALTriangulation::Cell_handle, int> f = *it;
            
            const Pointt& p0 = f.first->vertex((f.second))->point();
            
            const Pointt& p1 = f.first->vertex((f.second+1)&3)->point();
            const Pointt& p2 = f.first->vertex((f.second+2)&3)->point();
            const Pointt& p3 = f.first->vertex((f.second+3)&3)->point();
```

---

**EDIT**

```
for (auto f : T.finite_facets())
{

    //all convex hull facets pointing outside
    if (T.is_infinite(T.mirror_facet(f).first)){
        f = T.mirror_facet(f);
    }

    const auto cell = f.first;
    const int i = f.second;
        
    const Point& p1 = cell->vertex( T.vertex_triple_index(i, 0) )->point();
    const Point& p2 = cell->vertex( T.vertex_triple_index(i, 1) )->point();
    const Point& p3 = cell->vertex( T.vertex_triple_index(i, 2) )->point();

    Vector n = CGAL::normal(p1, p2, p3);
}
```

Comment: The iterator over the three vertices with `vertex_triple_index` gives the right orientation of the facet *seen from `cell`*. If you want a given orientation (on the convex hull for example), you still have to choose between the two representation of a facet: `f` or `T.mirror_facet(f)`.

Comment: Do you need to compute the normal only for the facets of the convex hull?

Comment: No, I compute all normals for the finite facets. But when a normal of the convex hull is not pointing outside is more visual evident: I'm making a cristal shader...

Comment: You should represent all facets twice, once for each of the two sides of a facet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orientation of a facet cannot be found that way. To set `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`, use that piece of code:

```cpp
const auto cell = f.first;
const int i = f.second;

const Pointt& p1 = cell->vertex(T.vertex_triple_index(i, 0)->point();
const Pointt& p2 = cell->vertex(T.vertex_triple_index(i, 1)->point();
const Pointt& p3 = cell->vertex(T.vertex_triple_index(i, 2)->point();
```

See the [documentation of `vertex_triple_index`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_3/structCGAL_1_1Triangulation__utils__3.html#a71288c8c2833f954a73090336ed60054).